# Parsing Xml response with key named "class" using retrofit

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I am using retrofit with simpleXmlConverter every where in the app it's working fine except one place where in response I'm getting class as key like following

```
<Car onRequest="0" id="10624043" group="Cars" class="PWAR" internalClass="LDAR" >Mercedes-Benz</Car>
```

while conveting to POJO it gives Class not found exception:unable to find class "PWAR"  i.e. the value of the key. I have tried not using this class key value using `restrict=false`  and `required=false` and create converter factory non-strict non of them helped
here is my pojo

```
@Root(name = "Car",restrict=false
public class Car  
{ 
@Attribute(name="id", required = false)
public String id;

@Text(required = false)
public String text;

@Attribute(name="group", required = false)
public String group;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Car onRequest="0" id="10624043" group="Cars" class="PWAR" internalClass="LDAR" >Mercedes-Benz</Car>
```

save this api response in a string then replace the word class as it is a keyword then parse the response